# Display dynamic data in listview, gridview

Tags: c#, wpf

I recives a `dictionary <string, string>` from an API.

I have to show this data on my WPF form in in grid view as Name and Value as two columns

```
<ListView Name="LstCustomProperties" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomPropertyTable}">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn  Header="Name"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Key}"  />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Value"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"  />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I also have two buttons on the form to add button to add new item or delete to delete any item. When user clicks ok the dictionary will get update according to current Name, value pair in the listview. I am not getting how to add and modify the current data in listview or shud I use any other control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using `ObservableCollection` here. so when you `insert / update / delete` any item from collection, the UI will automatically get refreshed.

see the following example:

```
public class CustomDictionary
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public CustomDictionary(string key, string value)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

public class CustomDictionaryCollection : ObservableCollection<CustomDictionary>
{

}


public class MyData
{
    public CustomDictionaryCollection CustomPropertyTable { get; set; }

    public MyData()
    {
        this.CustomPropertyTable.Add(new CustomDictionary("myKey", "myValue"));
    }
}
```

now when you add anything in the `CustomPropertyTable`, the `ListView` will automatically get updated.

**Hope this helps**

Comment: I don't want to add in object directly it will be in grid and when user click on it will be save to object and API will update the datastore.

Comment: sorry for accepting this too late as I was on vacation. 

One more thing I want to allow users to edit value member from the list view, any help in that matter will be highly appreciated